# Displaying duplicate Birthdays in Excel

Tags: excel, formula

I have a family list, and I am wanting to display on the dashboard who has a birthday today, additionally, there is sometimes more than one person on the same birthdate. I have been successful using a small test area, but the moment I try to use it on a grand scale, I am cooked. Is there a simpler way?
this is the current formula

```
{=IFERROR(INDEX($I$21:$I$24,SMALL(IF(TEXT($J$21:$J$24,"m/d")=$J26,ROW($J$21:$J$24)-ROW($J$21)+1),COLUMNS($J27:J27))),"")}
```

I am sure that it is where I am telling where the columns are that is throwing off the formula, but I barely understand what I am doing.

Comment: See if this helps [excel-birthday-reminder](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1445-excel-birthday-reminder.html)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Your explanation is clear but you should add a minimum information in order to get help as the actual input.

Comment: Look for posts mentioning duplicates or listing duplicates - covered often on here. I solved my issue by putting methods from 3 different answers together, included the use of aggregate().